# Jenkins pipeline quoting environmental variables

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a little bit of pain with Jenkins quotes. I'm trying to commit some changes to the repository and include in commit message few identification details

```
 stage('Commit changes') {
    steps {
        wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
            dir('deployment')
            {
                sh '''git commit -m "Creating new server in $VENDOR by"'''env.BUILD_USER_ID'''", buildID: "'''env.BUILD_ID'''" completed"'''
                sh 'git push origin $SRC'
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

The above is n-th iteration of my poor attempts. I appreciate any ideas how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sh("""
    git commit -m "Creating new server in ${VENDOR} by ${env.BUILD_USER_ID}, buildID: ${env.BUILD_ID} completed"
    git push origin ${SRC}
""")
```

Comment: Ok, didn't know it can be done this way. Much cleaner code, good to know. Works ok